# Cognos Report total values with same date

Tags: sql, cognos

I'm building a report in IBM Cognos report studio.

A set of data looks like this:
including location name, item name , item number , and days in inventory.

```
id     date       type      hours
1   10/27/2021    work       7
1   10/27/2021    overtime   1
1   10/24/2021    work       7
1   10/26/2021    work       7
```

I use total to sum the hours for the same date

```
total ([Hours] for [Date],[ID])
```

It returns:

```
id     date       type      hours
1   10/27/2021    work       8
1   10/27/2021    overtime   8
1   10/24/2021    work       7
1   10/26/2021    work       7
```

Then I tried a count and running count. then set count = 1 in the filter. Set object aggregate after.
Data returns:

```
id     date       type      hours  count
1   10/27/2021    work       1      1
1   10/27/2021    overtime   1      2
1   10/24/2021    work       1      1
1   10/26/2021    work       1      1
```

what I need:

```
id     date       type      hours 
1   10/27/2021    work       8
1   10/24/2021    work       7
1   10/26/2021    work       7
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I edited the question.  What I need is the total working hour for the same date.   But when I applied count filter, the total function will not work.

Comment: Can you explain the count filter?
Was this to control the number of rows returned?
For example you want to see 1 row per date
AND you want to include hours from all types
... if so, type colum is misleading and you may want to remove it (because it would include hours from work and overtime)

Comment: Several things.  First, there were not 8 hours of type work performed by id 1 on October 27th.  ID 1 performed 7 hours of type work and 1 hour of type overtime. I don't know why you would want to have the hours to be 8 but still have the type column in the projection. I'm not sure what the connection between your first query and your counts and running counts are.  I don't understand the connection between them and the table of what you need.

Comment: Do you understand why your expression returns 8 hours for both the work and overtime types for October 27th in your first query?  It is doing exactly what you asked of it to do.

Comment: a same employee can have different type of working hour per day.  over time , left early, late come.  I have to sum the actual working hours (for certain time code) for one day and I need them to be in one row.

Comment: In the example of what you need you list id, date, type, hours
and you also explain using the count to filter to show a roll up across types (see date 10/27 for id 1 for 8 working hours, but this is 7 for work and 1 for overtime)

Suggestion:
1) remove type to aggregate across type and have total hours for the id and date
or
2) make a crosstab and show work, overtime, etc, and the total for an id and date

If you want help with the crosstab concept, let me know and I'll add an answer

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is still a bit unclear, but if I understand it correctly, the query needs these data items:

| Name | Expression | Aggregation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | [id] | none |
| date | [date] | none |
| type | 'work' | none |
| hours | [hours] | Total |

Then add a filter with this expression:

`[type] in ('work', 'overtime')`

Include any values for [type] that you consider "work".

Alternatively, because your comments indicate your sample input and desired output are incomplete...

| Name | Expression | Aggregation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | [id] | none |
| date | [date] | none |
| type | case when [type] in ('work', 'overtime') then 'work' else [type] end | none |
| hours | [hours] | Total |

...without the filter.